# jqGrid Async request processing in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, jqgrid

Here is the problem that I'm seeing with jqGrid, using jqGrid version 4.4.1

I have an application that has two tabs containing a jqgrid in each of the tab content areas. I have REST web urls given for gridurl, editurl and other properties to load content into grid (loadonce=false, contentType=JSON)

When user navigates between these two tabs, its only the HTML attributes(in the DIV element of HTML body) which are replaced with the new attributes related to the current/active tab, which means I still have all my javascript components and ajax calls active in the background irrespective of tabs.. (implemented using backbone router, making it essentially a single page application)
Considering the above behavior of the application,

- When a user clicks on the other tab while the current one isn't done with loading fully yet(which means the ajax call isn't completed yet), the IE comes up with an error related to jqGrid shown as below (copied from IE)

Message: Unspecified error.
Line: 1438
Char: 40
Code: 0
URI: ../assets/js/plugins/jqGrid.js

Per my assumption, this is caused because the DOM ELEMENT for rendering the grid no longer exists by the time the ajax call is finished for the grid (since loading of second tab is removing the previous elements), and I'm not sure how can I check for the condition if grid exists after ajax call is done when I use ajax directly with the jqGrid using gridUrl, editUrl properties!

I found the above behavior specific to only IE and I use IE8.. (I tested it in all browsers which seemed to be fine)

Any idea to help this is appreciated.. Thank you very much